# Does it ever make sense to create a Global Secondary Index on the primary key?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm seeing this in a project.
Is there any value in doing this? It seems like the primary partition key would provide any value that a GSI would.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly duplicating the hash and sort key in the index? One use case could be if you want to maintain separate read capacity of some part of your application separate from the table read capacity.